# recompiling android app - native method not found

Tags: android, decompile, apk

Been trying at this for over a week, and I'm able to modify the needed sections, however I'm running into a major issue while trying to recompile the APK that is making the whole task atrocious. So I've sucked up my pride and am asking for help from other people.

I've been tasked with RE'ing an android app that has been giving me issues. To date, I've been able to decompile and recompile the app into an "almost working" apk. Without modifying anything, recompiling the app is fine, but when I try to run it on the AVM or an actual test device, it crashes repeatedly with a stack trace due to the following:

```
2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] E/[removed]﹕ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.[removed].crypto.openssl.OpenSSLWrapper.GenerateSeedHash:([BLjava/lang/String;)[B
```

I've removed the apk name as it is work-related information and hopefully not necessary to solving the issue.

Right before I get the stack trace, I've noticed a bit more of information that might be helpful:

```
    04-27 12:00:07.599    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] ﹕ CPU -- Arch same ? -> true
    04-27 12:00:07.599    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] : libcrypto.so.1.0.0 already exists
    04-27 12:00:07.599    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] ﹕ CPU -- Arch same ? -> true
    04-27 12:00:07.599    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] ﹕ libssl.so.1.0.0 already exists
    04-27 12:00:07.599    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.[removed].[removed]/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0xb310e1f0
    04-27 12:00:07.609    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/data/com.[removed].[removed]/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0xb310e1f0
    04-27 12:00:07.609    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.[removed].[removed]/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 0xb310e1f0, skipping init
    04-27 12:00:07.619    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.[removed].[removed]/files/libssl.so.1.0.0 0xb310e1f0
    04-27 12:00:07.619    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/data/com.[removed].[removed]/files/libssl.so.1.0.0 0xb310e1f0
    04-27 12:00:07.619    2173-2173/com.[removed].[removed] D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.[removed].[removed]/files/libssl.so.1.0.0 0xb310e1f0, skipping init
```

Any help is extremely appreciated as it's been quite some time tinkering, googling, etc. and I've had no success of getting the APK to run without issue.

Thanks all

Comment: Have you tried just modifying the smali? Actually a good first step would be to just run apktool to unpack and repack it without modifying anything. That's a good way to check if it's say, introspecting its certs for obfuscation purposes. Speaking of which, have you checked what kind of obfuscation if any it's using?

Comment: Yeah I've done that. After I kept running into issues I tried unpacking, repacking (no changes) and running. It has a built in tamper detection, but setting a breakpoint on that and bypassing it still causes the crash, so it's a tad frustrating... It doesn't seem to be using any obfuscation as I can convert it back into readable java, but if I'm missing anything please let me know.

edit - going to start looking into the cert thing. Unfortunately not familiar with that technique so will do research and try to find areas in the code reflecting it. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Antimony - since this crash is specifically related to native methods not being found in the .so, I figured it was something to do with the "No JNI_OnLoad found" error being spit out. Couldn't find any information online about explicit techniques to induce this for anyone RE'ing it.

Comment: Have you checked whether the unmodified app runs on your device? If the problem is libcrypto/libssl specifically, this is probably due to the issue of apps that link to openssl without including it suddenly crashing in newer versions of Android where the platform openssl changed. They're not supposed to do that but that doesn't stop app authors from doing it in practice.

Comment: @Antimony - yes. The default app works fine on the phone. Decompiling / Recompiling forces the issue. Seems strange that it can't recompile and work as it did originally. Wondering if its an issue with apktool or a built in defense.

Comment: Is this app available publicly? I could take a look if you want.

Comment: @Antimony yes it is, but unfortunately I feel it would violate some ethical agreement with my company or w/e. I appreciate the help! I'm going to approach the task differently as the end goal can be achieved in several ways. Modifying the apk would have been the easiest had it not been for that obnoxious issue.

Comment: You should ensure that the native method (which should appear in the Dalvik code) which is being called is present in the shared libraries which are being loaded. I'd start by checking for the `System.LoadLibrary` calls and see if there are any library that are no being loaded properly. Then check the two shared libraries to ensure the JNI method is actually defined -- it might actually be a specific shared library on the device which is not present on an AVD.

Comment: @diff - thanks for the input. I've essentially come to the conclusion that the checks I needed to bypass were being performed from by shared libraries and sadly don't have enough experience with IDA to find the areas where the checks are being performed. 

I put that route on hold and found several other security vulnerabilities that allowed me to bypass most of the restrictions. I would REALLY like to one day revisit this and try the IDA approach. Will have to find a mentor at some point though for that.